# Creating a submenu on hover over a an <li> in a drop down. Just like the Udemy website dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello guys i want to have a sub menu list when I hover over an `<li>` but i have tried but not getting the code. here is the example

```js
$("#giri").on("click", function() {
  $(".classic").fadeToggle(1000)
});

$(".checkit").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(".trying").fadeToggle(1000)
});
```

```css
.classic {
  margin-top: 0.6%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 470px;
  min-width: 270px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid rgba(40, 0, 30, 0.2);
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  color: #555;
  background: #4CA1AF;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C4E0E5, #4CA1AF);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #C4E0E5, #4CA1AF);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple" id="giri">
            <div class="classic">
                <ul id="helpo">
                  <li id="macas" class="hot checkit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> Go and Skate</li>
                   <hr id="break2"> 
                    
                    
                  <li id="macas" class="hot checkit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> Join Ninos group now..</li>
                   <hr id="break2">
                    
                  <li id="macas"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> Buy some new laptops</li>
                   <hr id="break2">
                    
                  <li id="macas"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> View Laptop settings </li>
                   <hr id="break2">
              </ul>
           </div>                

    </i> APPLE</a>
```

what i am trying to build is just as the same as the drop down menu in
   (https://www.udemy.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure CSS. Just specify, that the subelements are only visible when the parent is hovered.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

span:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
span > ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
span > ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
span > ul li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #73AC21;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
span > ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>Nav
<ul>
  <li>Test
  <ul>
    <li>subtest</li>
    <li>subtest</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Test2
  <ul>
    <li>subtest2</li>
    <li>subtest2</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
</span>
```

Comment: Can u make the text 2 to be of the same height with the first one, that is the height being the same but change of content just the same height with the drop down

Comment: You could add a little jQuery for that: `$('li >ul').css('height', ''+$('span>ul').height());`. When you want to have the started at the same y-position you have to remove the `position: relative;` from `span > ul li > ul` and experiment with the `top`-value, which is currently set to `0px`

Comment: Yeah I got it but is there any way to avoid the flicking of the sub menus, just to make it to show immediately i enter the next li in the drop down and not when the mouse touches the text in the li I will be <.} if there is a way

Comment: By reducing the `margin` and positioning the elements right next to each other you should be able to get rid of the flickering. When there are no pixels left between the elements, everything should be fine.

Comment: You can check out this pen: https://codepen.io/tlaub/pen/KqRqPb maybe it helps you with your problem ;) I used some jQuery there to connect the red 'Nav'-button with the root dropdown. The rest works with pure CSS.

Comment: You are there my manchi I got it, it is really working fine hoping to know you

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#giri").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $(".classic").fadeToggle(1000)
})
```

```css
.classic{
margin-top: 0.6%;
display: none;
position: absolute;
height: 470px;
min-width: 270px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 3;
border: 1px solid rgba(40,0,30,0.2);
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
color: #555;
background: #4CA1AF;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C4E0E5, #4CA1AF);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #C4E0E5, #4CA1AF); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="giri">APPLE</a>
  <i class="fa fa-apple" >
        <div class="classic">
            <ul id="helpo">
              <li id="macas" class="hot checkit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> Go and Skate</li>
               <hr id="break2"> 


              <li id="macas" class="hot checkit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> Join Ninos group now..</li>
               <hr id="break2">

              <li id="macas"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> Buy some new laptops</li>
               <hr id="break2">

              <li id="macas"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-pull-right"></i> View Laptop settings </li>
               <hr id="break2">
          </ul>
       </div>                
</i>
```

Comment: what i meant is this: in the dropdown menu when i hover over the li tag i wish to get another container floating to the right of the li tag and of the same height.just like the one in www. udemy.com

Comment: I recommend you to use @talaub answer with little bit animation added. because it is more faster than using jquery.